# how use Terrafrom to deploy azure logic app standard's workflows

Tags: azure, azure-logic-app-standard

I can deploy logic App standard using terraform however i am unable to deploy or import the workflows inside logic App standard .. any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you are unable ? could you please share with us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can deploy logic App standard using terraform however i am unable to deploy or import the workflows inside logic App standard

If you are facing issues while deploying your workflow, One of the workaround that you can try is to write an ARM template for the workflow and deploy ARM template to configure the workflow in the logic app.

```
// Create an instance of logic app and configure the tags
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logicapp" {
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = var.shared_env.rg.name
  tags                = var.shared_env.tags
}

// Deploy the ARM template to configure the workflow in the Logic App
data "template_file" "workflow" {
  template = file(local.arm_file_path)
}

// Deploy the ARM template workflow
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "workflow" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_logic_app_workflow.logicapp]

  resource_group_name = var.shared_env.rg.name
  parameters = merge({
    "workflowName" = var.workflow_name,
    "location"     = "westeurope"
  }, var.parameters)

  template_body = data.template_file.workflow.template
}
```

If you are trying to deploy actions from terraform, Here is an [example](https://www.mikestephenson.me/2021/12/29/setting-up-logic-app-standard-with-terraform/) that you can refer to.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [azurerm_logic_app_standard](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard)
2. [Deploying a LogicApp with Terraform](https://azapril.dev/2021/04/12/deploying-a-logicapp-with-terraform/)

Comment: Thanks @SwethaKandikonda-MT yes it seems workflow/code is out of scope of TF and as you suggested we need to using other coding to get the workflow and code deployed -- i am worried about using ARM templates within TF other have suggested using AZ CLI within a pipeline to build the workflow/code