# Is there a terraform block that create multiple workflows in a single logic App in Azure

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

below configuration creates 2 logic Apps, but I am trying to create 2 workflows in the same logic App:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
 name     = "workflow-resources"
 location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
 name                = "workflow1"
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
 name                = "workflow2"
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

I tried creating a standard logic App but couldn't find an option to create workflows within that logic App.

Comment: "create 2 workflows in the same logic App" - what does it mean? Your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: @Marcin,you're right. On the UI, when I create a standard logic App, there is a "Workflows"  tab under the logic App name. There, I am able to create as many workflows as I want. Is there a way to do that with terraform?                                                             For a non standard logic App, only one workflow can be created. am I wrong?

Comment: Logic app itself is a workflow and we can be able to create multiple logic app workflows using `azurerm_logic_app_workflow` terraform resource. @Armand

Comment: Are you trying to configure [this](https://i.imgur.com/oiWE4Gu.png) using terraform? @Armand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround for your requirement. That is create an ARM template and pass it in the terraform code using [template_deployment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment) resource and deploy the ARM template to configure the workflow for logic app with terraform as detailed in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866517/how-use-terrafrom-to-deploy-azure-logic-app-standards-workflows).

```bash
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
 name     = "Jahnavi"
}
data "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "example" {
  name                = "stlog"
  resource_group_name = "Jahnavi"
}
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
 name     = "logicappflow"
 location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

data "template_file" "workflow" {
  template = file(local.<workflow_schema_filepath>)
}
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-01"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  parameters = merge({
    "workflowName" = var.workflow,
    "location"     = "westeurope"
  }, var.parameters)
  dependsOn = [
  data.azurerm_logic_app_standard.main.name
  ]

  template_body =  data.template_file.workflow.template
}
```

Refer [document](https://www.mikestephenson.me/2021/12/29/setting-up-logic-app-standard-with-terraform/#content) for more information related to the above issue.

*And if you want to create multiple workflows using consumption plan then you can follow the below steps and it worked for me as expected.*

```bash
variable "workflows" {
  type = map(string)
  default = [ "workflow1", "workflow2"]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
     name     = "workflow-resources"
     location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
     for_each = toset(var.workflows)
     name     = logic_${each.value}
     location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
     resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]