# azure logic apps standard workflow creation using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I am currently deploying logic apps standard using terraform and want to create a set of standard workflows. I can create the workflows manually though the azure porta but - how can I create the workflows in terraform? does terraform support this? possible to link the module or how this could be achieved

any help on this much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use Terraform? GitHub actions is pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Have you tried this [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard) template. @G T

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a logic app standard workflow using terraform.

*Terraform code:*

```bash
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "logicapp_std_storage" {
    name                     = "strplatlasta${var.environment_name}"
    resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "logicappplan" {
    name                    = "asp-platform-logicapps"
    location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    kind                    = "elastic"
    is_xenon                = "false"
    per_site_scaling        = "false"
    reserved                = "false"
    tags                    = {}
    zone_redundant          = "false"
    sku {
        tier = "WorkflowStandard"
        size = "WS1"
    }
}
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "logicapplogs" {
    name                = "log-platform-logicapps"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    sku                 = "PerGB2018"
    retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "platform_logicapp_appinsights" {
    name                = "${var.context_prefix}-ai-platform-logicapps-${var.environment_name}"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    application_type    = "web"
    workspace_id        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logicapplogs.id
}
resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "helloworld" {
    name                        = "la-hello-world"
    location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    app_service_plan_id         = azurerm_app_service_plan.logicappplan.id
    storage_account_name        = azurerm_storage_account.logicapp_std_storage.name
    storage_account_access_key  = azurerm_storage_account.logicapp_std_storage.primary_access_key
    storage_account_share_name  = "la-hello-world"
    
    https_only                  = true
    version                     = "~3"

    site_config {
        always_on                   = false
        dotnet_framework_version    = "v4.0"
        ftps_state                  = "Disabled"
        pre_warmed_instance_count   = "0"
        app_scale_limit             = "1"
    }

    identity  {
        type                        = "SystemAssigned"
    }
}
```

```bash
variable "workflow_name"{}

data "template_file" "workflow" {
  template = file(local.arm_file_path)
}

// Deploy the ARM template workflow
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "workflow" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_logic_app_standard.hello-world]

  resource_group_name = var.shared_env.rg.name
  parameters = merge({
    "workflowName" = var.workflow_name,
    "location"     = "eastus"
  }, var.parameters)

  template_body = data.template_file.workflow.template
}
```

[image]

[image]

*References:*

1. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866517/how-use-terrafrom-to-deploy-azure-logic-app-standards-workflows) &
2. [Blog](https://mikestephenson.me/2021/12/29/setting-up-logic-app-standard-with-terraform/)

Comment: thank you Jahnavi, would it be possible to upload the full code? I understand how to create the logic app, but still struggling with the workflow creation. If i could have a look at the example that you have written above / have deployed?. Very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: I have already provided the code for workflow creation as well. Just give the path of JSON file and you are good to proceed further. Have you tried that? @GT

Comment: I create the workflow, but instead of adding the workflow to the existing logic-app-standard that I created, it created an instance of 'logic app consumption' with the workflow from the template. 

Could you tell me what i am doing wrong? or how this could be fixed?

Comment: Can you [refer](https://azapril.dev/2021/04/12/deploying-a-logicapp-with-terraform/#content) this once. @GT