# How to create a workflow in Standard Logic App

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I have created a `azurerm_logic_app_standard` Logic App in my resource group.
Now, I want to create a workflow in this Logic App to automate some task but I am not sure of how to create a workflow in Standard Logic App. Need help please.

Comment: Are you trying to create workflow in azure portal or any command?

Comment: It’s confusing, you’ve managed to create a logic app via CLI but you can’t work out how to create a workflow?!! You sound capable so what’s the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the terraform code you tried? @varun ahuja

Comment: I am looking for a terraform code to create a workflow in Stanard Logic App: azurerm_logic_app_standard. tried multiple ways to define a workflow through terraform but none is working. Though I am able to create from portal but my requirement is to create from terraform.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a workflow in a standard logic app using terraform. But there is no direct resource existed for creation of logic app workflow resource. It must be done with [`azurerm_template_deployment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment) .

Firstly, define a logic app workflow using an arm `Json` template and provide that arm file path in terraform template deployment resource as shown below.

```bash
data "template_file" "workflow" {
  template = file(<arm_file_path>)
}
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "workflow" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_logic_app_standard.hello-world]

  resource_group_name = var.shared_env.rg.name
  parameters = merge({
    "workflowName" = var.workflow_name,
    "location"     = "eastus"
  }, var.parameters)

  template_body = data.template_file.workflow.template
}
```

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626618/19785512) by me for detailed steps on the issue.

*Prior to the above, deploy a standard logic app using below terraform code.*

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "caroline"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "logicapp_std_storage" {
    name                     = "strplatlasta"
    resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "logicappplan" {
    name                    = "asp-platform-logicapps"
    location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    kind                    = "elastic"
    is_xenon                = "false"
    per_site_scaling        = "false"
    reserved                = "false"
    tags                    = {}
    zone_redundant          = "false"
    sku {
        tier = "WorkflowStandard"
        size = "WS1"
    }
}
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "logicapplogs" {
    name                = "log-platform-logicapps"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    sku                 = "PerGB2018"
    retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "platform_logicapp_appinsights" {
    name                = "ai-platform-logicapps"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    application_type    = "web"
    workspace_id        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.logicapplogs.id
}
resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "helloworld" {
    name                        = "la-hello-world"
    location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    app_service_plan_id         = azurerm_app_service_plan.logicappplan.id
    storage_account_name        = azurerm_storage_account.logicapp_std_storage.name
    storage_account_access_key  = azurerm_storage_account.logicapp_std_storage.primary_access_key
    storage_account_share_name  = "la-hello-world"
    
    https_only                  = true
    version                     = "~3"

    site_config {
        always_on                   = false
        dotnet_framework_version    = "v4.0"
        ftps_state                  = "Disabled"
        pre_warmed_instance_count   = "0"
        app_scale_limit             = "1"
    }

    identity  {
        type                        = "SystemAssigned"
    }
}
```

[image]

References:

1. [Blog](https://www.lekman.com/blog/2022/03/deploy-logic-app-standard-workflows/) by @lekman
2. [Blog](https://azapril.dev/2021/04/12/deploying-a-logicapp-with-terraform/) by @AZApril